# How to search for a date in timestamp field?

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

I have a database and a table with below attributes:

```
Column: Date 
Type: TIMESTAMP 
Attributes: ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
Default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

So each data will showing up in this format: "2013-07-06 14:32:18"

I'm looking for a SQL query that shows retrieves rows in "2013-07-06".

**What I'm tried:**

```
select * from posts where date between "2013-07-05 00:00:00" and "2013-07-07 00:00:00";
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to obtain only the date part of your `TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE DATE(date) = '2013-07-06'
```

However, such a query cannot benefit from an index on the `date` column (if one exists); instead, one can use a range as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE date >= '2013-07-06' AND date < '2013-07-07'
```

MySQL will implicitly add a time of `00:00:00` to the date literals, but you can include them explicitly if so preferred.

Note that [`BETWEEN ... AND ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) is inclusive of its operands, so `BETWEEN "2013-07-05 00:00:00" AND "2013-07-07 00:00:00"` will include all records on `2013-07-05` and `2013-07-06` as well as any records at `00:00:00` on `2013-07-07`.

Comment: Coincidentally needed this query today, which happens to be same date few years later :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from posts where date(date) = "2013-07-06";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well.

```
select * from posts where date like "2013-07-05%"
```

Answer (score -1):

use following query

```
select * from posts where date >= "2013-07-06 00:00:00" and date < "2013-07-07 00:00:00";
```